# How to convert a DropDownList Value in INT Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

neI have a DropDownList with a list of value.

I need in my code USE the value selected by the User in the DropDownList AS INT DataType (numeric).

At the moment I am using this code below (CONVERTING DATATYOES). 
Script work just fine.

But **I would like to know if exists an alternative way to do it**.

Any ideas it is very appreciate. Thanks for your time.

---

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="uxPageSizeUsersSelector" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="uxPageSizeUsersSelector_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

---

```
        int myPageSize = Convert.ToInt16(uxPageSizeUsersSelector.SelectedValue.ToString());
        PageSize = myPageSize;
```

Comment: Note that you are actually converting the value to a `short` and then to an `int` when you assign it to your variable. `short` is `Int16`, `int` is `Int32`.

Comment: You don't need to call `SelectedValue.ToString()` because `SelectedValue` is already a string. Is there some reason why you're converting to an `Int16` instead of an `Int32`? Otherwise that's indeed the way to do it.

Comment: For Anthony I used Int16 because the dropdownlist contains just very small numbers. Does it make sense?

Comment: You partially used `Int16` is the point. It's OK to use it, just know you are storing the result in a type that can represent far more data, since `myPageSize` is declared as a 32-bit integer. For consistency's sake and to leave your intention unambiguous, I would recommend that the right side conversion match the left side type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the try parse method.  This will make sure that your value is an int, and if not, allow you to handle the problem instead of throwing an exception:

```
int myPageSize;

if(int.TryParse(uxPageSizeUsersSelector.SelectedValue, out myPageSize))
{
     //SUCCESS
}
else
{
    ///handle problem here.
}
```

You can do it for Int16 DateTime etc. too.